# how to get all code of stored procedure in c#.net window and create textFile of storedprocedure in C#.net window Application

Tags: c#, database

I Want get All Code of stored procedure from database and convert that procedure in textfile and save that textfile in particular path in c#.net window application.

Answer (score 3):

With thanks to [David Cumps](http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2006/10/18/681812.aspx) (Assuming SQL Server):

```
SELECT text 
FROM syscomments 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = '{0}') 
ORDER BY colid
```

Execute this query from your app then concatenate the results.

Comment: Work, but i get two row for my storedprocedure

Comment: 1 stored 1 row instead query return 2 row, seems that the text is divided into two parts

Comment: @Flatlineato: Yes, the text may be divided into multiple parts. That's why you need to concatenate the results. You could use `String.Concat` or a `StringBuilder` - there are a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the code for a stored procedure, you're probably going to have to query the system tables in the database. Look at the documentation for whatever RDBMS you're using.

As far as saving a text file goes, take a look at [this howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx).